# Only sending Stream Started message once Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks, twitch

I wish to make it so when a user goes live on a certain list, a message is sent to a channel. However, as I have this part of the code on a 60 second asyncio loop, I am not sure how to do this. It just keeps posting the live message every 60 seconds.

I have tried using `If` statements and have tried messing about with variables, however this just continues going on without errors.

Does anyone know of a certain function that can make it so it only posts the live message once without repeating itself until the user's stream goes offline again?

Thanks, my code is below:

```
response = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels', headers=headers, params=params)

final = response.json()

finali = final['data'][0]['is_live']

finale = final['data'][0]['thumbnail_url']

finaly = final['data'][0]['title']

finalo = final['data'][0]['started_at']

print(final)


async def live_poster():
    if finali:
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        counter = 1
        print("someone live")
        channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
        while not client.is_closed():
            counter += 1
            embedVar2 = discord.Embed(title="" + x + " is now live on Twitch!", description="" + finaly + "", url="https://twitch.tv/" + x + "", color=0x0C8BC2)
            embedVar2.set_image(url="" + finale + "")
            await channel.send("@everyone")
            await channel.send(embed=embedVar2)
            await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

client.loop.create_task(live_poster())
```

Comment: You could declare another variable which will capture the previous state of the `is_live` and compare it with the new results each time.

Comment: @NuKeFluffy how would I do this? Thanks.